# Getting trouble with template argument

Tags: c++, class, templates, types, arguments

This is my 1st template and I get some errors when running this code. Any help would be great!

```
class polinom;

template <typename Tip>
class node {
  node <Tip>* next;
  Tip coef;
  int grad, nr;
public:
  friend class polinom;
};

class polinom
{
protected:
  node<Tip>* prim;      <--------- THIS LINE
};
```

ERRORS :  "Tip" was not declared in this scope and 
           template argument 1 is invalid

Comment: And please indent this code

Comment: Adjusted code format, added "c++" tag

Comment: ""Tip" was not declared in this scope". I agree with the compiler. I don't see where you declared it.

Comment: You see in class node you marked "Tip" like template parameter. It's something like placeholder for real type(int, char*, float, string, polinom). But below in class polinom you don't have this placeholder. It's another scope. There you need to use actual type. The type you want it be substitution of Tip in class node.

Answer (score 1):

The `template` statement applies to the thing that follows it, not to the rest of the file. So as it stands, your `polinom` is *not* a template class. Try this:

```
template <typename Tip>
class polinom;

template <typename Tip>
class node {
  node <Tip>* next;
  Tip coef;
  int grad, nr;
public:
  friend class polinom<Tip>;
};

template <typename Tip>
class polinom
{
protected:
  node<Tip>* prim;
};
```